# Decrypted Trucrypt drive won't mount in another computer

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt

I am upgrading computers and will use Bitlocker on the new machine.
I decrypted my system drive on the old machine that was encrypted with TC so that I can more easily transfer my old data across.
TC decrypted much faster than I expected, but so far OK.
However, when I put the drive into a USB enclosure, the new computer says the drive is not formatted.

Putting the drive back into the old machine and booting up, I check TC. It of course can not find an encrypted drive, nor can it decrypt the system drive.

Any hints on what I've missed or what has gone wrong?

Comment: Is a drive letter assigned to that drive?

Comment: There's only one drive? How did you decrypt the old drive? And immediately afterwards did it still work / boot ok? Normally, you would leave the old drive encrypted, and just mount & copy the data onto the new computer / drive, in another encrypted container or folder, to maintain security (writing the decrypted data to a hard drive would be insecure)